# Keeping metadata when overwriting file in S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

When I overwrite a file to S3, I am losing the metadata since it is treated as a new object. I am trying to keep the existing original metadata of a file when overwriting the file in S3. I know from the docs that you cannot modify the metadata of an object in a S3 bucket, but how do I "copy" the existing metadata onto the new overwritten object?

For example, I have this method below:

```
public void uploadToS3(File file, String key, String bucketName) {
    // original metadata
    ObjectMetadata objMetadata = client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key);
    // How do I set the new overwritten object to have this metadata above??

    try {
        client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file));
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
    } catch(AmazonClientException e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
    }
```

How do I "point" the new object to have the same metadata as the object that was just overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling [`AmazonS3#putObject(PutObjectRequest)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-), first call [`PutObjectRequest#withMetadata(ObjectMetadata)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withMetadata-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-).

```
ObjectMetadata objMetadata = client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key);
client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file)
        .withMetadata(objMetadata));
```

Be aware that according to the S3 documentation on [Object Key and Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html), only certain pieces of metadata are allowed to be updated.  Because of that, you might need to take extra steps to make sure your request doesn't attempt to modify something it shouldn't.

```
ObjectMetadata objMetadata = client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key);
// Call a helper method that clones only what you need to maintain in the metadata.
ObjectMetadata clonedMetadata = cloneMetadata(objMetadata);
client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file)
        .withMetadata(objMetadata));
```

Comment: This works for copying a source file, I suppose, but what about copying from a file not yet in S3?  For example, replacing (overwriting) an existing file with a custom Content-Encoding header without having to set that header again?